# Api lost lost param

Tags: c#, api, angular, asp.net-core

Hi I have this code to run my api method

```
export class MessageService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    addMessage(textToSend: string) {
        return this.http.post("/api/SendMessage", textToSend); //<- Everytime i have some text in textToSend and this is ok 
    }
}
```

And after in my Api my param is equals to null

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/SendMessage")]
public void SendMessage(string msg) //null value
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: Of course it wont pass any, its a query parameter you request in your method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution 1:

```
addMessage(textToSend: string) {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ textToSend });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post("/api/SendMessage/", body, options);
}

// Server side -1
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/SendMessage")]
public void SendMessage([FromBody]IDictionary<string, string> msg)
{
    var textToSend = msg["textToSend"];
}

// Or create a model and use it

//Server side -2
public class Model
{
    public string textToSend { get; set; }
}
public void SendMessage([FromBody]Model model)
```

Possible solution 2:

```
addMessage(textToSend: string) {
    return this.http.post("/api/SendMessage/" + textToSend);
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/SendMessage/textToSend")]
public void SendMessage(string textToSend)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: So i try solution 2 and my component send value as textToSend.

Comment: in networks when I look on request i see "api/SendMessage/someTextFromMyInput"

Comment: Because it appends `textToSend` to end of url, so it is expected. If you don't want this try solution 1. Did you try solution-1?

Comment: Nope cuz i dont  know where i can find Headers and RequestOptions and firstly i use second solution and in first solution i dont know why we have 2 same method with different parameters

Comment: Actually solution-1 has two possible solution in server side. You can use which you want.

Comment: Ok I try first one and it works very well :) If u can explain me what's kind of magic is this second sendMessage(string ...) cuz I use breakpoint on this method and it just ignored

Comment: Probably model binding doesn't match.

Comment: @ademcaglin: #2 isn't RESTful. In RESTful services, the payload is always to be submitted via post or put body (depending on if its idempotent operation or not) and also not very save, as the input isn't encoded  and could contain invalid values (like `/`, `?`, `&`, `=`) which as url may be interpret differently. Last but not least, depending on browser and server (dunno if ASP.NET Core has a limit there), the url has a max limit (i.e. ~2048 chars on IE)

Answer (score 2):

Your controller action is accepting a query parameter, not a router parameter or model.

If you want to accept a route parameter, you need to add it to the route.

If you want to pass a model or value in the body, you must mark the parameter with `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/SendMessage")]
public void SendMessage([FromBody]string msg)
{
    MessageBox MsgBox = new MessageBox();
    MsgBox.AddMsgToMsgBox(msg);
}
```

If you don't define anything, the controller expects the parameter to be passed as query `/api/SendMessage?msg=someMessage` (which you shouldn't do in a REST service, as it's not very "RESTful"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 addMessage(textToSend: string) {
    return this.http.post("/api/SendMessage", msg); //<- Everytime i have some text in textToSend and this is ok 
}
```

changed the name of the variable to match the one you are expecting in the controller

Comment: You know the difference between TypeScript which runs in browser and C# which runs in the server?